# Apply Plugin not working in gradle with NDK

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-ndk, realm

I am trying to add realm to my app. Their documentation states that I need to add class path dependency to the project level build.gradle file. And Apply the realm-android plugin to the top application application level build.gradle file. (https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/)

I did that but I am getting this error:

```
Error:(2, 0) 'com.android.application' or 'com.android.library' plugin required.
```

My project gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.0-alpha4'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.1.1"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

My app gradle uses NDK:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'


Properties properties = new Properties()
properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
def superpowered_sdk_path = properties.getProperty('superpowered.dir')

model {
    repositories {
        libs(PrebuiltLibraries) {
            superpowered { // this is where you declare the "superpowered" static library
                headers.srcDir "${superpowered_sdk_path}"
                binaries.withType(StaticLibraryBinary) { // attaching library files to each platform
                    def platformName = targetPlatform.getName()
                    if (platformName == "armeabi-v7a") {
                        staticLibraryFile = file("${superpowered_sdk_path}/libSuperpoweredAndroidARM.a")
                    } else if (platformName == "arm64-v8a") {
                        staticLibraryFile = file("${superpowered_sdk_path}/libSuperpoweredAndroidARM64.a")
                    } else if (platformName == "x86") {
                        staticLibraryFile = file("${superpowered_sdk_path}/libSuperpoweredAndroidX86.a")
                    } else if (platformName == "x86_64") {
                        staticLibraryFile = file("${superpowered_sdk_path}/libSuperpoweredAndroidX86_64.a")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    android { // main settings for your application
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.2"


        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.superpowered.crossexample"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 16 // more than 95% of all active Android devices
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
    }

    android.ndk { // your application's native layer parameters
        moduleName = "SuperpoweredExample"
        platformVersion = 16
        stl = "c++_static"
        CFlags.addAll(["-O3", "-fsigned-char"]) // full optimization, char data type is signed
        cppFlags.addAll(["-fsigned-char", "-I${superpowered_sdk_path}".toString()])
        ldLibs.addAll(["log", "android", "OpenSLES"]) // load these libraries: log, android, OpenSL ES (for audio)
        abiFilters.addAll(["armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86", "x86_64"]) // these platforms cover 99% percent of all Android devices
    }

    android.sources.main.jni {
        source {
            srcDir "jni"
            srcDir "${superpowered_sdk_path}/AndroidIO"
        }
        dependencies {
            library "superpowered" linkage "static" // this is where you attach the "superpowered" static library to your app
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.12.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
}
```

Comment: I should note that while Realm does not work with the experimental plugin, it does however work with the Gradle CMake Support. See sample codes for that [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master-cmake).

Comment: Same problem, did you find any other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using the experimental plugin? `apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'`. Is that correct?

Realm currently doesn't work with the experimental plugin. See https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2539